# is there a software can simulate handwriting

Tags: windows, fonts, handwriting

I am looking for a Windows software that can simulate handwriting, so I write on my keyboard and get handwriting word as a result

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Lifehacker 'how to' on the use of website that converts your own handwriting to a font:
http://lifehacker.com/206685/geek-to-live--make-your-own-font

Answer (score 2):

I use [1001 Free Font](http://www.1001freefonts.com/)s.  They have a whole section with just Handwriting fonts.

Answer (score 2):

If you do go down the fonts route you could use this site:

Link: http://www.identifont.com/

to help you to choose the font that suits your requirements most closely.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution by far is "My Font Tool for Tablet PC" PowerToy from Microsoft (see http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/tabletpc.mspx ) In the extremely likely event that you don't have a TabletPC available, find a Wacom style tablet and plug it in to a PC running Vista ( other than "Home Edition") to generate the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You just need the proper font. If none of the fonts bundled with Word suit your needs, you can find more on the internet, e.g. [free handwriting fonts](http://www.free-fonts.com/handwriting_fonts.html) (found through google, no own experience).